# Handling simultaneous update in JSOM CRUD application built using content editor web part

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-jsom

I have a form for CRUD operations on a list build using JSOM and the content editor web part.
It contains a datalist control, in which the options are populated from another list (named details). When an user click on a 'save' button, the code checks if he has picked a value from the options in the datalist  element, if not then the new value is added back to the details list, where each item should be unique.

The problem is if two users use the JSOM form simultaneously and update the same "new value" in the datalist element,then the same value is stored twice in the details list.How to handle such situations?

Comment: See [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9695.sharepoint-2010-how-to-apply-unique-value-constraint-in-person-and-group-column.aspx). Can you apply a unique constraint on the source column? That should be adequate to resolve the issue.

Comment: I cannot use any server side code